# Compression of *.js and *.css files going through the Azure endpoint

Tags: javascript, css, azure, compression, azure-cdn

I am trying to set up *.js and *.css compression on the fly on the Azure platform. I have an application running on Azure App Services. It serves uncompressed *.js and *.css files. I want to use the CDN profile so I added an endpoint. and configured it to compress JS and CSS files.
[image: Configuration]
But the files are still served uncompressed even if I access the App Service via the endpoint. (the uncompressed file has about 3 MB, compressed about 600 KB).
[image: Uncompressed]
Do I miss some configuration, that allows bypassing the uncompressed files through the CDN endpoint?

Is this a correct approach for App Services how to compress files on the fly?

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a correct approach for App Services how to compress files on
> the fly?

Yes it is the correct approach to compress files on the fly.

Follow the below steps to troubleshoot whether the compression is completed or not:

1. To check whether your files are being returned compressed, you need to use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or your browser's [developer tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/).
2. Check the HTTP response headers returned with your cached CDN content.
   If there is a header named `Content-Encoding` with a value of **gzip**, **bzip2**, or **deflate**, your content is **compressed**.

[image]

**There are several possible causes, including:**

- The requested content is not eligible for compression.
- Compression is not enabled for the requested file type.
- The HTTP request did not include a header requesting a valid compression type.
- Origin is sending chunked content.

**Note**:

As with deploying new endpoints, CDN configuration changes take some time to propagate through the network.

Usually, changes are applied within **90 minutes.**

If this is the first time you've set up compression for your CDN endpoint, you should consider waiting **1-2 hours** to be sure the compression settings have propagated to the POPs.